# telegram-desktop: qt.svg: Error while inflating gzip file: SVG format check failed

Tags: wayland, gzip, qt, sway, svg

I use telegram-desktop on arch linux in sway. It sometimes crashes, so I started it from terminal. This way I find out telegram spams this message:

> qt.svg: Error while inflating gzip file: SVG format check failed

How can I fix this ?

Comment: This used to be a known problem: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2067662#p2067662 But was assessed to be solved in modern Qt and or modern telegram. (Probably telegram just shipped a broken icon) so you need to tell us which version of qt5 and of telegram you're using!

Comment: How can I check qt version telegram is using ?